# find letter in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

how to query oracle to find me columns that contain numbers from 0-1000

I have tried queries like:

```
select (Column_name)  
from  (table_name) 
where regexp_like(CREDIT_BANK_BRANCH,'^[0-999]$');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression:

```
^([0-9]{1,3}|1000)$
```

**Explanation:**

Regular expressions cannot evaluate numeric expressions, so you have to treat everything as characters, so:

Find any group of numbers one to three characters long: `[0-9]{1,3}` or just the number 1000.

Pipe means "or" and parenthesis are necesary to limit the escope of the expression.

**Shorter version:**

```
^(\d{1,3}|1000)$
```

Tested:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex to `^[0-9]+$` (or shorter `^\d+$`) if you want only rows containing digits in that column returned.

If you want to find records with a non-digit character, then use `[^0-9]` (or shorter `\D`).

See [Using Regular Expressions in Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm) for more details.

Comment: i'm geting a error did you see that the number is 0-1000 i'm sorry it's new to me......if you have a query that i can find all the numbers in the column it's will be perfect.

Comment: maybe i didn't ask the question right....i have a table inside the table i have one column that i need to query...i need to find all the rows that contain letters